# git fork - when does origin get synced from upstream?

Tags: git

1. I create a fork from source (once off)
2. I clone from the fork (once off)
3. I make changes in my local workspace, commit, and push to 'origin' which is the fork
4. I create pull request to owner from 'origin' to 'upstream'
5. Owner merges my changes to 'upstream'
6. If I need get latest from 'upstream', I run 'git pull upstream'

(Let's say there is no code conflicts at all)

During the above process, I didn't see the remote 'origin' get synced from remote 'upstream'. Is it a problem? I am new to fork so I cannot understand. 
-- Now I realised when I push to 'origin' which is the fork, I am pushing my changes and the changes from 'upstream'. So the origin get synced.

Another question is, how can I do above all operations in one place (git command or github desktop client)? Currently I do some here and do the other there.

Comment: It really depends on how you have your branched configured....

Comment: If/when the owner of upstream merges your pull request, your code makes it into upstream.  Often, that will be a merge commit which you will then retrieve when you pull.  That merge commit is different than the commit in your repo, but the content of the files is the same (unless there have been other commits unrelated to yours)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Do you mean, when owner merges my changes, the 'upstream' will get my changes merged, the 'origin' will get synced then? The 'merge' is not one direction update, instead, it is two directions update?

Answer (score 0):

> During the above process, I didn't see the remote 'origin' get
>   synced from remote 'upstream'.

In the workflow you've described, your `origin/master` branch never
gets synchronized to `upstream/master`.

When operating against an upstream repository, you will need to
periodically resync your local copy of the repository with the
upstream in order to ensure that you are working with a current
version of the code, which is necessary for your changes to apply
cleanly.  This is easiest if you *don't* make changes on the `master`
branch in your local copy, but instead always operate on a feature
branch.  In this case, your workflow is something like:

```
# update your local copies of the remote repositories
git remote update

# start working on your code, using the `upstream/master` branch
# as the base.
git checkout -b my-feature upstream/master

[...work happens here...]

# push your changes to your github fork of the upstream repository
git push origin my-feature
```

At this point, you could submit a pull request from
`origin/my-feature` to `upstream/master`.  When you next want to make
a change, you would follow the same process, again starting by basing
your work on a current version of the `upstream/master` branch.

You'll note that in this workflow we generally ignore both your local
`master` branch and the `master` branch of your fork on GitHub (aka
`origin/master`).

> Another question is, how can I do above all operations in one place
>   (git command or github desktop client)? Currently I do some here and
>   do the other there.

The GitHub folks provide the [hub](https://github.com/github/hub)
command line tool that can act as a wrapper for `git`, providing you
with a single interface for both `git` and GitHub operations.   When
properly installed, you can run `git pull-request` in order to create
a pull request.